# File size and storage limits on Trello

Tags: trello

On one of the blog posts it mentions a 10 Meg upload limit... I'm assuming this is per file?

Is there a total limit/quote per account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 10MB per-file-limit.

Comment: Has this been updated? And if not can you provide an order of magnitude estimate of what the limit mighg be?

Comment: see the other answer `The 10MB file upload only applies to files uploaded from your computer. It does not apply to files attached from Google Drive, Dropbox, Box or OneDrive.`

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

- 10MB per file.
- No account/board limit, no limits for drive/dropbox attachments.

## Quoting their (updated) [manual](http://help.trello.com/article/769-adding-attachments-to-cards)

> ### Limitations
>
> **There is a 10 MB file** upload limit per attachment. However, Business Class and Trello Gold members have a 250 MB file upload limit per attachment. It's not possible to upload attachments via the mobile site. **There is no limit on the number of attachments you can have on a card or board**. Neither is there an account data storage limit.
>
> The 10MB file upload only applies to files uploaded from your computer. It does not apply to files attached from Google Drive, Dropbox, Box or OneDrive.